# How to return data from a service as a promise in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I am trying to send data from a service as a promise to my controller but had no luck after trying out a few options. The http service by default returns a promise, but I want to send data as promise from one controller to another. My service class looks like: The add functions are there to set data from another controller and the get functions are to get that data in another controller.

**Services**

```
    return {


      add : function(incategories){
      categories=incategories;
      console.log(subcategories)
    },

       addcatname:function(incat){
       category=incat
       console.log(category)
    },


      get : function(){
      return categories;
      console.log(category)
       },

       getcatname:function(){
        return category;
       },
```

And the function that gets data from the controller looks like this.

**Controller**

```
 vm.getSub=function(){
          vm.category=CategoryService.getcatname();
          vm.subcategories=CategoryService.get();
          vm.index = 0;
          vm.array1 = [];
          for(var i=0; i<vm.subcategories.length/2;i++)
          vm.array1.push(i);    
          return true;
 }
```

The code where the values are being set is:

```
vm.submit=function(category){
          subCategoryService.getsubCategories(category).then(function (response) 
         {
            console.log(response)
            CategoryService.addS(response.data.data.category_name);
            CategoryService.addsub(response.data.data.sunbcategories);


                                        })
            $location.path('/subcategory');    

}
```

**My HTML**

```
<h1 class="header">{{'CATEGORY'|translate}}</h1><br>
<div ng-controller="CategoriesController as catCtrl" class="category-content">
    <table class="table-content" class="category-content" ng-show="catCtrl.getcategories()">
<tr ng-repeat="i in catCtrl.array"  ng-init="index = i*2">
    <td layout-align="space-around center" ng-repeat="category in catCtrl.categories.slice(index,index+2)" >


            <md-button md-whiteframe="6" ng-click="catCtrl.submit(category)" class="category-button"  aria-label="{{category}}">
               <div class="category-button-text-translation">{{category|uppercase| translate}}</div>
                <img ng-src="assets/images/categories/{{category}}.png" alt="{{category}}">
                <div class="category-button-text-english">{{category|lowercase}}</div>
            </md-button>
            <span flex></span>
     </td>
</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The data from subCategoryService.getsubCategories(category) is from $http service and after getting that data i am setting the values in a service so another controller can access them.

Now i want the first two lines of the function to receive the data as promises from the service. How will I be able to accomplish this? Before, every time I was getting data was from $http service so I had no problems but i am kind of lost right now. Thanks!!

Comment: is this getCatName and get funtion in service is http service(promise)?.Could you please post the exact code

Comment: getCatName and get functions are just getters. The values are being set in the add functions that i have put above them. the code where the values are being set is added above in the post.

Comment: so do you want to make it custom promise??

Comment: Yeah, i edited my post above to add more relevant code if you could have a look please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the get and getcatname to custom promise you should have to use **$q** service. In inorder to do that inject **$q** service on your service and use like below

```
  getcatname:function(){
      //$q please inject $q on your service
       ̶l̶e̶t̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶

         ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶.̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶(̶c̶a̶t̶e̶g̶o̶r̶y̶;̶)̶
      return ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶.̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶;̶ $q.resolve(category);
    }
```

in the controller you can get this category with promise callback

```
CategoryService.getcatname.then(function(response){

vm.category=response;
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I injected the q service just like u said but it returns undefined. I was getting objects when i wasn't using the q service and doing without though. What could be wrong?

Comment: @BleachedAxe where it's undefined??

Comment: It tries to access the get in the other controller even before its been added to the service by the previous controller. Dont know what i am doing wrong :(

Comment: @BleachedAxe can u please share the complete error you are getting in the console. basically custom promise is not a complicated thing.

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:66
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18037)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18269)
    at done (angular.js:12387)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12613)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12541)

Comment: I also added my html above. It doesnt even go to category page. It shoots that error message when i click a button on the previous page. Basically when it goes to categories page i put ng-show on the function to get and display categories. But its not even getting there. All this was working when i was using rootScope but that's an extremely bad thing to do here.